# Artifactory Docker 404 after upgrade to 7.4.1

Tags: docker, artifactory

After an Artifactory upgrade to 7.4.1 from 6.10.4, I've made the necessary port changes and the UI works fine, but I'm seeing the following in the artifactory-service log when attempting to use docker login via the [subdomain method](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Getting+Started+with+Artifactory+as+a+Docker+Registry#GettingStartedwithArtifactoryasaDockerRegistry-TheSubdomainMethod):

> Request /v2/ should be a repo request and does not match any repo key

The docker login command prompts for authentication but then returns:

> Error response from daemon: login attempt to http://<local-docker-repo>.<artifactory-url>.com/v2/ failed with status: 404 Not Found

Artifactory is running in a Kubernetes cluster behind an nginx ingress controller, which has an ingress set up specifically to serve https://<local-docker-repo>.<artifactory-url>.com via the same backend as the Artifactory UI. It seems like some URL rewrite functionality is not working, I'm just not sure how I've misconfigured it as I had no problems in the previous version.

Curl results as follows:

```
curl -i -L -k http://docker-local.<artifactory-url>.com/v2/
HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
Server: nginx/1.15.9
Date: Mon, 21 Sep 2020 00:25:32 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 171
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://docker-local.<artifactory-url>.com/v2/
X-JFrog-Override-Base-Url: ://docker-local.\<artifactory-url>.com:80
X-Forwarded-Port: 80
Host: docker-local.artifactory.<artifactory-url>.com
X-Forwarded-For: 10.60.1.1

HTTP/2 401 
server: nginx/1.15.9
date: Mon, 21 Sep 2020 00:25:32 GMT
content-type: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1
content-length: 91
www-authenticate: Basic realm="Artifactory Realm"
x-artifactory-id: ea0c76c54c1ef5de:45761df0:174ad9a6887:-8000
x-artifactory-node-id: artifactory-0
x-jfrog-override-base-url: ://docker-local.<artifactory-url>.com:443
x-forwarded-port: 443
host: docker-local.<artifactory-url>.com
x-forwarded-for: 10.60.x.x
strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains

{
  "errors" : [ {
    "status" : 401,
    "message" : "Authentication is required"
  } ]
```

As a workaround I've enabled Repository Path as the Docker access method, which works fine -- still not sure where subdomain is going wrong.

Comment: What do you get if you `curl -i https://<local-docker-repo>.<artifactory-url>.com/v2/`

Comment: Oh, you were missing the https and got redirected from http. That response looks normal, you're talking to the registry server. For basic auth, you should be able to pass `-u 'user:pass'` replacing user and pass with your creds, and I enclosed in single quotes to avoid issues with special chars.

Comment: When I pass my credentials, I see an HTTP 404 as the last curl response, similar to what docker login is reporting.

Comment: Generate the Nginx reverse proxy configuration from the Artifactory v7 for the sub-domain method and compare the rewrite rules from the generated Nginx config to the Nginx ingress.

Comment: The important part of the 404 is to see whether it came from artifactory or kubernetes or something else, that's visible in the headers. If you know it's artifactory, it's time to dig into those container logs and check with the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the $repo variable in the nginx rewrite rules provided by Artifactory was not getting populated for some reason. Since we only have a single registry being used in the subdomain method, I updated the rewrite rule to provide the repo name which resolved the issue.

To illustrate:

`rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/$repo/$1/$2;`

was changed to:

`rewrite ^/(v1|v2)/(.*) /artifactory/api/docker/docker-local/$1/$2;`